# What does Rust's unary || (parallel pipe) mean?

Tags: rust, syntax

In [Non-Lexical Lifetimes: Introduction](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/), Niko includes the following snippet:

```
fn get_default3<'m,K,V:Default>(map: &'m mut HashMap<K,V>,
                                key: K)
                                -> &'m mut V {
    map.entry(key)
       .or_insert_with(|| V::default())
}
```

What does the `|| V::default()` mean here?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html the official document

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is a closure with zero arguments. This is a simplified example to show the basic syntax and usage ([play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=11e98bb5c3bc581816469f8fbc9b215c&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let c = || println!("c called");
    c();
    c();
}
```

This prints:

```
c called
c called
```

Another [example from the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html):

```
let plus_one = |x: i32| x + 1;

assert_eq!(2, plus_one(1));
```

Answer (score 28):

It's a zero-argument lambda function.